# RabbitMQ: how to list all routing_keys of an exchange

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

On the [RabbitMQ Management plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html), is it possible to list all routing_keys of an exchange ?

Comment: yes http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html

Comment: @Rachel-Gallen thanks for the link, I am not sure how is it answering my question

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, or better you can see all bindings where your exchange is a source, in this way:

```
/api/exchanges/vhost/name/bindings/source
```

for example a my test exchange:

```
https://myServer/api/exchanges/myvhost/myTopic/bindings/source
```

And the result is:

```
    {"source":"myTopic","vhost":"fftjrrmf","destination":"myPersistentQueue","destination_type":"queue","routing_key":"kern.#","arguments":{},"properties_key":"kern.%23"},
{"source":"myTopic","vhost":"fftjrrmf","destination":"test2","destination_type":"queue","routing_key":"rout_key2","arguments":{},"properties_key":"rout_key2"}]
```

This JSON contains all information you need.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks @Gas, what I was interested in was a list of all the routing_keys also those not bound by any queue

Comment: Sorry, But I didn't understand, you can't have a routing_key not bound.
"The purpose of the routing key is to selectively match only specific (matching) messages published to an exchange to the bound queue"

Comment: Messages are published to an exchange with a routing_key. Then they can be used to bind queues. I'd like to know all the keys published, bound or not yet bound to a queue.

Comment: Then you have to use [Alternate Exchanges](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ae.html) and filter all messages by routing key (consume them and collect routing key). As to original question, you can view exchange bindings in management panel, nothing more.